# Is there a way to make this animation smoother, by keeping the output window the same size between frames?

Tags: python

I made this stick like animation in python, but it closes between each print because of the clear_output() function. Is there a cleaner way to achieve the animation look than using this function?

```
from IPython.display import clear_output
import time
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sys
import datetime as datetime
import random
from pprint import pprint

class color:
   PURPLE = '\033[95m'
   CYAN = '\033[96m'
   DARKCYAN = '\033[36m'
   BLUE = '\033[94m'
   GREEN = '\033[92m'
   YELLOW = '\033[93m'
   RED = '\033[91m'
   BOLD = '\033[1m'
   UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
   END = '\033[0m'
def fatality(winner,loser):

  print(rf"""
        O
     o_/{color.BOLD + color.YELLOW+ winner.name[0]+ color.END }\_o
        |
       / \

    """)
  time.sleep(.5)
  clear_output()

  print(   f"""
       O
     {color.BOLD + color.RED   +"O"+color.END}_/{color.BOLD + color.YELLOW+ winner.name[0]+ color.END }
        |
       / \

    """)
  time.sleep(.5)
  clear_output()
  print(   f"""
         O
        {color.BOLD + color.YELLOW+ winner.name[0]+ color.END }--{color.BOLD + color.RED   +"O"+color.END}
        |
       / \

    """)

  time.sleep(.5)
  clear_output()
  print(   f"""
        O
        {color.BOLD + color.YELLOW+ winner.name[0]+ color.END }--  {color.BOLD + color.RED   +"O"+color.END}
        |
       / \

    """)


  time.sleep(.5)
  clear_output()
  print(   f"""
        O
        {color.BOLD + color.YELLOW+ winner.name[0]+ color.END }--    {color.BOLD + color.RED   +"O"+color.END}
        |
       / \

    """)
  time.sleep(.5)
  clear_output()

  print(   f"""
        O
        {color.BOLD + color.YELLOW+ winner.name[0]+ color.END }--          {color.BOLD + color.RED   +"O"+color.END}
        |
       / \

    """)


  time.sleep(.5)
  clear_output()

  print(rf"""
                      O
      {color.BOLD + color.RED   +"O"+color.END}             _/{color.BOLD + color.CYAN   +loser.name[0]+color.END}\_
                      |
                     / \
                    /   \

    """)

  time.sleep(.5)
  clear_output()
  print(rf"""
                     O
        {color.BOLD + color.RED   +"O"+color.END}           _/{color.BOLD + color.CYAN   +loser.name[0]+color.END}\_
                      |
                     / \
                    /   \

    """)

  time.sleep(.5)
  clear_output()
  print(rf"""
                     O
             {color.BOLD + color.RED   +"O"+color.END}      _/{color.BOLD + color.CYAN   +loser.name[0]+color.END}\_
                      |
                     / \
                    /   \

    """)

  time.sleep(.5)
  clear_output()

  print(rf"""
                     O
                {color.BOLD + color.RED   +"O"+color.END}  |_/{color.BOLD + color.CYAN   +loser.name[0]+color.END}
                      |
                     / \
                    /   \

    """)

  time.sleep(.5)
  clear_output()
  print(rf"""
                     O
                   {color.BOLD + color.RED}|_/{color.BOLD + color.CYAN   +loser.name[0]+color.END}
                      |
                     / \
                    /   \

    """)
  time.sleep(.5)
  clear_output()
  print(rf"""   {color.BOLD + color.RED}
                     O
                   |_/{color.BOLD + color.RED   +loser.name[0]+color.RED}
                      |
                     / \
                    /   \

    """)


  time.sleep(.5)
  clear_output()
  print(rf"""   {color.BOLD + color.RED}

                     \|/
                    \/ \/
                   \/   \/

    """)

class temp_class:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

temp_class1 = temp_class("M")
temp_class2 = temp_class("P")
fatality(temp_class1,temp_class2)
```

Comment: You can use tkinter.Canvas the use after

Comment: Is there a way to use it just in jupyter notebook without opening anything else?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Jupyter Notebook.

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.clear_output):

> `IPython.display.clear_output(wait=False)` Clear the output of the
> current cell receiving output.
> Parameters:    `wait : bool [default: false]`
>
> Wait to clear the output until new output is available to replace it.

So you just need to replace all your `clear_output()` calls with `clear_output(wait=True)`

I'd suggest a slight refactor:

```
def animate(frames, wait_time=0.5):
    for frame in frames:
        time.sleep(wait_time)
        clear_output(wait=True)
        print(frame)
```

Then you can adjust your time between frames in one place, and you can store the frames in a list. You can then reuse you animate function for other animation frames.